# MySQL schema into PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm sure this has been done before many times but I'm having trouble finding the simple solution, probably because it's hard for me to wrap my mind around it.  The context is a custom PDO wrapper.

**Summary:** I want to produce a two-level (?) array `schema` to easily access a MySQL table schema in two ways:

1. Column type/null/defaults by column name (something like `schema['fieldname']['null']).
2. Array of fields (maybe produced by `array_keys(schema)`) to use with array_intersect to validate query fields.

**Details:**

```
$schema = $pdo->run("DESCRIBE " . $tablename);
(magic happens here)
// validate input field array by field names
$queryfields = array_intersect(array_keys($schema), $inputdata;
// check format of input data
foreach ($schema as $column => $key) {
  if ($column['type'] == 'datetime') {
    $inputdata[$key] = date_format($inputdata[$key], 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  }
}
```

Don't get too bogged down in the details.  Basically I want to turn a flat array of arrays into the same thing but grouped by the column name.

Comment: Or in other words, I want to make the values of one array to become the keys of the associative arrays

Comment: `array_values()` -> `array_flip()` -> `array_intersect()`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have an answer.  Maybe there's a faster/better way to do this that doesn't involve actually walking through the array, but maybe this is the best way.

```
$schema = array();
$rows = $pdo->query("DESCRIBE " . $table);
// refactor array of associative arrays using column name as key
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  // pull off the first key-value which is the column name
  $key = array_shift($row);
  // add the rest of the array to $schema with the column name as the key
  $schema[$key] = $row;
}
```